# jquery values username and email differentiation

Tags: jquery, string

I am making a form and i need the UserName to be totally different from the email address. 
Example below:

email : leonsmitthes@hotmail.com 
username : leonsmitthes
The above should not pass so the user has to enter a totally different username like Benzema or something
can anyone help? p.s an easy enough jquery code please as i am new to all this.
Thanks

Comment: totally different is how much different can username be leons or mitthes or mitthesleons ?

Comment: Hello there, something like username can not match the first characters before the @ sign in the email.

Comment: You realize that a pure jQuery check will be easy to circumvent?

Comment: I guess you're asking about some kind of jQuery form validation.  Where is _your_ code attempt?

Answer (score 2):

Just check for this

```
email.indexOf(username) == -1
```

that will check for the username in the email string

Comment: thank you for the code but in webconsole it says email.indexOf is not a function?

Comment: @LeonSmith i think you need to learn some javascript

Comment: this is for jquery not javascript!

Comment: @LeonSmith then you *really* need to learn some javascript. JQuery is just a javascript library.